# Sudo resetting environment variables

Tags: mac-osx, environment-variables, sudo

Whenever I use the sudo command, none of my environment variables appear to be preserved.

I've tried modifying the sudoers file, by removing the env_reset specification.

```
#Defaults   env_reset
```

I've also tried adding the env variable that I want using env_keep.

```
Defaults   env_keep += "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

I'm using Mac Snow Leopard.

Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH seems to be excluded from the 
    Defaults   env_keep += "Defaults   env_keep += "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
"

If you try any other variable it works for example 
    Defaults   env_keep += "VAR"

You can probably get over this by providing DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on the commandline
for example (where cmd is the command you want to pass DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH)

```
# sudo DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH cmd
```

Hope this helps